# Manipulate Numpy array inside C with SWIG

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig

Trying to pass a Numpy array to a C method and modify its content there, is it even possible? The idea is to do as little data copying (speed and memory reasons) as possible.

Trying out something like this currently:

**test.c**:

```
void testMethod(int** values) {
  // code
  *values = other_pointer;
}
```

**test.i**:

```
/* File : test.i */
%module test
%{
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
%}
%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
    import_array();
%}

%{
extern void testMethod(int** values);
%}

%apply (int **ARGOUT_ARRAY1) {int **values};
extern void testMethod(int** values);
```

I modified the **numpy.i** file adding:

```
%typemap(in,
         fragment="NumPy_Fragments")
  (DATA_TYPE **ARGOUT_ARRAY1)
  (PyArrayObject* array=NULL, int is_new_object=0, DATA_TYPE* temp=NULL)
{
    array = obj_to_array_contiguous_allow_conversion($input,
                                                   DATA_TYPECODE,
                                                   &is_new_object);
    temp = (DATA_TYPE*) array_data(array);
    $1 = &temp;
}
%typemap(argout)
  (DATA_TYPE** ARGOUT_ARRAY1)
{
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,(PyObject*)array$argnum);
}
```

Running it:

```
input = numpy.array([1,2,3])
test.testMethod(input)
```

Works, i.e. it compiles and I can print the contents of the array in C but content of input stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, one a bit hacky way would be to change the typemap to something like this:

```
%typemap(in,
         fragment="NumPy_Fragments")
  (DATA_TYPE **ARGOUT_ARRAY1)
  (PyArrayObject* array=NULL, int is_new_object=0, PyArrayObject_fields* temp=NULL)
{
    array = obj_to_array_contiguous_allow_conversion($input,
                                                   DATA_TYPECODE,
                                                   &is_new_object);
    if (!array) SWIG_fail;
    temp = (PyArrayObject_fields*)array;
    $1 = (DATA_TYPE**) &temp->data;
}
%typemap(argout)
  (DATA_TYPE** ARGOUT_ARRAY1)
{
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,(PyObject*)array$argnum);
}
```

@Edit: after a bit of testing the above would work but produce Segmentation Fault exception if we reuse the Python `input` array. The solution is to change the mapping type from `ARGOUT_ARRAY1` to `INPLACE_ARRAY1`.

Comment: The typemaps using `INPLACE_ARRAY` as well as `ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY` are defined in the `numpy.i` header. They both work "by reference".

Comment: @JensMunk but 1) they require the C method signature to accept `data_type* arg` and not `data_type** arg` 2) require the method signature to take the pointer and the length. Right? Or is there a different way to use them?

Comment: Single pointer is enough to modify the content of the array for input, `INPLACE_ARRAY`. For output, `ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY` a double pointer is provided, the python array is referencing an array residing in the C code. If the array is updated in C, the numpy array residing in Python is also updated.

Comment: I see, ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY is doing something very similar to what I wrote, but don't they still require the C method to be in a form `void method (int** array, int size)`? The methods I'm using don't take `size` and I can't modify them. That was part of the reason why I wrote my own mapping without dimension parameter.

Comment: Yes and no. If you create a `NumPy` array in Python, it will always have a size and without that, the C program cannot tell if it is going out of bounds. You could write a wrapper with an extra argument, which is hardcoded to the size and use SWIG for wrapping the wrapper. I usually prefer to use `ARGOUTVIEWM_ARRAY` and use `malloc` on the C side. This creates a managed array, which is properly cleaned, when the `NumPy` array is cleared in Python